# [AngularJS][UI-Router] Display view in view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I don't know how to describe my problem but maybe code help :)

**What i want:** Display create_modal.html in views/accounts/index.html

app.js:

```
angular.module('myApp', [
 'ui.router'
]).config(function($stateProvider) {
      $stateProvider
          .state('index', {
            url: '/',
            template: 'Index template'
          })
          .state('about', {
              url: '/about',
              template: 'About template'
          })
          .state('panel', {
              url: '/panel',
              templateUrl: 'views/panel/index.html'
          })
          .state('accounts', {
              url: '/panel/accounts',
              templateUrl: 'views/accounts/index.html'
            })
          .state('accounts.create', {
                views: {
                    create_modal: {
                        templateUrl: 'views/accounts/partials/create_modal.html'
                    }
                }
          })
});
```

main index.html

```
<div class="container" ui-view></div>
```

views/accounts/index.html

```
[...]
<div ui-view="create_modal"></div>
[...]
```

When i go on /accounts/ i see accounts/index.html but create_modal.html not load in view. 
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Giving the UI-View a name is only setting the name of the view, not setting the state to the state you want to use.  You should name the UI-View whatever you want the name to be called.

You could try applying a UI-sref to an anchor tag if you want to test it out, but what you want to do is to change the $state variable to your desired state.

```
$state.go('accounts.create');
```

Another thing you could try doing would be to set a URL for that state and navigate to that URL.

```
.state('accounts', {
    url: '/panel/accounts',
    templateUrl: 'views/accounts/index.html'
})
.state('accounts.create', {
    url: '/create',
    templateUrl: 'views/accounts/partials/create_modal.html'
});
```

Hope that helps, I'll include the documentation for UI-View for your reference.

[Click here!](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-view)

Comment: Thanks for reply, i solved this problem (see comment above) but as you say when i have `<a ui-serf="accounts>link</a>` transition does not work only work when i change for accounts.create_modal i must more read about $state.go()

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to a dev environment, but have you tried setting a empty url for your 'accounts.create' state ?

That's how they do it here:

https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/sample/#/contacts

Here's the source code (look for the "contacts.list" state):

https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/sample/app/contacts/contacts.js

Hope that helps.

Comment: After question i added empty url but still does work but i solved problem by doing this:

`.state('accounts.create', {
                views: {
                    create_modal: {
                        templateUrl: 'views/accounts/partials/create_modal.html'
                    }
                }
          })`

I changed to: 

`.state('accounts.create', {
              url: '',
              templateUrl: 'views/accounts/partials/create_modal.html'

          }
      )` and I changed `<a ui-serf="accounts>link</a>` for <a ui-serf="accounts.child>link</a>

This worked for me.